# Background image is 1200px wide and body width is 900px.

Tags: html, css

I need your help with a site i'm putting together. I'm a noob and have been given a design that has the body with designed to 900px wide but they have given me an image that is 1200px wide. They want the image to span the full 1200px wide, so essentially there will be 300px overlap on either side of the page. I can't quite figure out how to do this, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Can't you move the body content into a <div> with a width of 900 and then just set the background image to be 1200px for <body>?

Comment: You mean shrink not span right?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to accomplish what they want is to make the image a background-image in CSS.

1. Set up a div that will contain the image (as a background), and position it on the page relative to where you want it to be.

   ```
   <div class="background"></div>`
   ```
2. Either fill the div with content to give it a height or define a fixed height, say 400px.

   ```
   <style>
    .background {
       height: 400px;
       width: 100%;
     }
   </style>
   ```
3. Now, set the background properties to achieve what  you want.

   ```
   <style>
   .background {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(URL_TO_IMG);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
   }
   </style>
   ```

JSFiddle example here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcj3cco5/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. The only problem is i still end up with this http://imgur.com/chFCfZW and I want the image to take up that whole white area. Right now it stops at 960px

Comment: That looks like it's happening because the div the background image is being applied to has a max-width of 960px (aka your grid). In order for that div to span wider than your grid, you need to have an outside grid of 1200px (for large background divs like this) and and inside grid of 960px for content.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle example for you. http://jsfiddle.net/qcj3cco5/   Obviously I used an inner grid of 200px instead of 960px. And I set my outside container to be 100% width to show you, but you could make this width:1200px; margin: 0 auto; to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

to cover the exact space you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to do this but still ended up with this http://imgur.com/chFCfZW it's still cutting off the image at 960px wide, when I want it to cover that white space you see which is 1200px

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    background: #ccc url(image_folder/image_name.extension) np-repeat 0 0 center;
}
#otherelement{
    /*Style Your Page Whatever you want...*/
}
```